# How to safely clock_cast days?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

I'm using [HowardHinnant/date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) in lieu of the new C++20 calendar/timezone facilities that are not yet available in Clang/GCC. My question applies equally to both implementations: How do I safely `clock_cast` `time_point`s having `days` duration?

When I try:

```cpp
using namespace date; // or using std::chrono in C++20
tai_time<days> tai{days{42}};
sys_days sys = clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(tai);
```

I get a "no viable conversion" error for the last statement. It turns out the result uses a duration that is `common_type<days, seconds>`, which comes from `utc_clock::to_sys()` that's used in the conversion. The common duration type is `std::chrono::seconds`, so it's normal that it can't be directly converted to a `days` duration.

I can get it to compile if I use an explicit `duration_cast`:

```cpp
using namespace date; // or using std::chrono in C++20
tai_time<days> tai{days{42}};
auto casted = clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(tai);
sys_days sys{std::chrono::duration_cast<days>(casted.time_since_epoch())};
```

... but I'm worried that the result might by off by a day due to the truncation (especially for dates preceding the epoch). Is this the correct way to do what I'm trying to do? Should I be using `floor` instead of `duration_cast`?

Why is there even a `std::common_type_t<Duration, std::chrono::seconds>` in `utc_clock::to_sys()` anyway? Shouldn't it simply return the same duration type?

Comment: There are very few places where you can have your question answered by the author of the library.... The author is very generous with his time in that regard, and we all benefit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that the `clock_cast` insists on at least `seconds` precision is because the offset between the epochs of `system_clock` and `tai_clock` has a precision of `seconds`:

```
auto diff = sys_days{} - clock_cast<system_clock>(tai_time<days>{});
cout << diff << " == " << duration<double, days::period>{diff} << '\n';
```

Output:

```
378691210s == 4383.000116d
```

So a `days` precision cast would be lossy.  Here's another way of looking at it:

```
cout << clock_cast<tai_clock>(sys_days{2021_y/June/1}) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2021-06-01 00:00:37
```

I.e. [TAI is currently 37 seconds ahead of `system_clock`](http://leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm) in calendrical terms.

If all you want is the date, I recommend `round<days>(result)`:

```
cout << round<days>(clock_cast<tai_clock>(sys_days{2021_y/June/1})) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2021-06-01 00:00:00
```

One could conceivably use `floor` in one direction and `ceil` in the other, but that would be very error prone.  `round` will do fine since the offset from an integral number of days is currently only 37 seconds and growing quite slowly.

Comment: I appreciate this answer so much, as well as your work on this very useful library. Glory to you and your house!

Comment: You've been a long time customer of my date lib.  I appreciate that. :-)